# Create a SQL query to find the sum of invoices for 2021 and 2020 and calculate the growth percentage for the year 2021 in SQL

Tags: sql

I am new and trying to solve a problem. I have two tables `Invoice` and `InvoiceLineItem`. I am able to find the total for 2021 and 2020 but unable to  calculate the growth percentage for the year 2021. I know the growth percentage rule but am unable to implement it by joining two tables.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
SELECT 
    SUM (UnitPrice * UnitQuantity) AS 'Grand Total 2021 & 2020'
FROM 
    dbo.Invoicelineitem 
LEFT JOIN
    dbo.Invoice ON dbo.Invoicelineitem.InvoiceKey = dbo.Invoice.InvoicKey
WHERE
    dbo.Invoice.InvoiceDate LIKE '2021%' 
    OR dbo.Invoice.InvoiceDate LIKE '2020%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
Select SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(i.InvoiceDate) = 2020 THEN UnitPrice*UnitQuantity END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(i.InvoiceDate) = 2021 THEN UnitPrice*UnitQuantity END)
       (SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(i.InvoiceDate) = 2021 THEN UnitPrice*UnitQuantity END) /
        SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(i.InvoiceDate) = 2020 THEN UnitPrice*UnitQuantity END)
       ) as ratio
From dbo.Invoicelineitem ili JOIN
     dbo.Invoice i
     ON ili.InvoiceKey = i.InvoicKey
where i.InvoiceDate >= '2020-01-01' AND
      i.InvoiceDate < '2022-01-01';
```

Note that a `LEFT JOIN` is unnecessary.

You can adjust the formula for whatever you want it to be.

Comment: Isn't growth percentage = change in value divided by original value?  Shouldn't formula be (Sum(...2021...) - Sum(...2020...)) / Sum(...2020...) ?  ...and times 100 to make it a percent.